# Can you use EGit for free?

Tags: git, egit

I want to set up EGit (Git in eclipse).  I've set up my local repository but I want to be able to set up a repository on my server instead of a remote server like GitHub and paying for it.  Is this possible to do?  And if so can someone point me in the direction a good tutorial please?

Cheers in advance,
Alexei Blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read through [Lars Vogels article about Git](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Git/article.html), which is absolutely brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install git on your server. One chapter in pro git cover this topic:
[Chapter 4 pro git](http://progit.org/book/ch4-0.html)

Alternatively Bitbucket provides private repositories for free with git:
[BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/)

Comment: Thanks tune2fs  I'll have to tell a few of my friends about this as they're paying $25/month through Git hub for just ten users which sounds like a bad deal in comparison to BitBucket :)